# Combined CSS selectors dont work?

Tags: css

This works:

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: red;
}

input:-moz-placeholder { 
   color: red;  
}

input::-moz-placeholder { 
   color: red;  
}

input:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: red;  
}
```

But this does nothing, at least on Chrome:

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder,
input:-moz-placeholder, 
input::-moz-placeholder,
input:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: red;  
}
```

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the warning in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#grouping):

> A comma-separated list of selectors represents the union of all
>   elements selected by each of the individual selectors in the list.
>
> **Warning**: the equivalence is true in this example because all the
>   selectors are valid selectors. If just one of these selectors were
>   invalid, the entire group of selectors would be invalid.

Then, the group of selectors doesn't work because each browser only accept its vendor prefix, but the other ones are invalid.